# angular 2 select (combo) - ignore back button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a select control contains options (like combobox) in my HTML template and i want to ignore if the user press on back button.

```
   <select>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
   </select>
```

How can i do it? 
My project was written in ng2.

Comment: you want to ignore what?

Comment: ignore back button -> will not go to prev page